# How to model: Team <-(1) --- (N)-> Employees, with a twist; Better Pattern?

Tags: entity-framework, oop, design-patterns, database-design

I have to model and create in a SQL Server database a simple relationship...

A Team can have zero or more Employees assigned to it; An Employee can only be assigned to a single team.  Simple enough...  Here is the twist that I am struggling with...

The Team has a TeamLeader, who is an Employee.  A TeamLeader can be assigned to a single Team.  So, I added the TeamLeaderId long to the Team and gave TeamLeaderId a unique index.  I created a foreign key relationship between the TeamLeaderId in Team to and EmployeeId in Employees.

Is this the best model for this situation, or is there a better pattern?

Thank you for your help and guidance,

Mike

Comment: Your solution is correct. If you need to ensure this rule at the database level, your Unique index is the simplest way to go (and most times the simplest solution is the best one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to this question depends much on the usage of the system:

1. If the Team is created and employees assigned, and then finally the team leader is chosen among any of the team members, its a good choice you have made.
2. On the other hand, if an employee is hired as a team leader, and he will always be assigned as a team leader it is better to add this "type" of information to the Employee table (othervise adding/removing an employee requires extra uneeded logic to handle the TeamleaderId and potential future "types").

Answer (score 2):

For the constraints you laid out this looks right. But it seems you would be better off with a link table between Team and Employee. Why limit an employee to a single team or make it mandatory for an employee to be in a team at all? Today someone (you?) may think this is the only way, tomorrow it may be different.

Comment: This violates the YAGNI principle, though.

Comment: YAGNI (I had to look that up) is nice for things that are easily changed or extended. This however is your DB structure which is at the root of your system. That is, a dependency to everything you will be creating on top of it. Concidering the self imposed limitation defies common real-world scenarios and covering those now would be cheap, YAGNI is likely to bite you in the ass later. And it will be painful. I would even say that inappropriate YAGNI is responsible for most of the software development expenses today.

Comment: It's probably not YAGNI, though, to set up facilities which make it easier to modify the system without fear, that is: automated tests, database migrations, and the like. I believe, as always, “it depends”! 

Comment: Thanks for the link. It agree it does depend. Often I would agree with Sam and rather finish the work than leaving it halfway. A typical case is a component of some sort. YAGNI would tell you to only implement the parts you will need now. You will end up with a component that only works for the problem YOU are working on. The next guy will have to wrap his head around your half-baked component and finish it or worse, just add the features he needs. Or he won't notice your component is disfunctional and introduce a bug by using it. That is maintenance hell. And it can be unimaginably expensive.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to remove TeamLeaderId field from Team table and create new table TeamLeaders (with an unique key [EmployeeId in Employees + TeamId in Teams])

Now, you can change your mind and remove team leaders from your business domain model without pain: just drop teamleaders table.